# How do I make an f-string distinguish between an integer and a string?

Tags: python, f-string

both

```
x = 1
f"{x}"
```

and

```
x = '1'
f"{x}"
```

give

```
'1'
```

as output. How do I get `"1"` and `"'1'"` as output?

Comment: I'm a little surprised I couldn't find a duplicate for this. Good question to have on the site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `!r` modifier to get the objects `repr` instead of its `str`:

```
f"{x!r}"
```

Comment: Of course, if it's that trivial, just use `repr(x)`.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to get the specific output to read:

"'1'" (text with quotes) and

 "1"  (text without quotes)

 you can use:

```
f"{x}"     #text without single quotes
f"'{x}'"   #text with single quotes
```

this only works when you alternate quotes. like this: " ' ' " , ' " " '

```
f'"{x}"'
```

results in: '"1"' as output